# can make something like bridge between two network interface in linux (docker, openvswitch)

Tags: linux, docker, network-programming, openvswitch

First, I'm not good at network programming and english.

I want to create new bridge to alternate docker default bridge to limit outgress bandwidth.

I tried to using tc to control container's outgress bandwidth.

After several attempts, I thought that to limit container outgress bandwidth, tc must run in container. but in my environment, it is not allowed.

So i considered about using openvswitch(ovs).

But create ovs bridge as docker default bridge is not working.

So I created docker container using option --net=none and attach ovs veth peer to container. It works, but some features are restricted that something like can not see net I/O in docker stats.

**Main question is below.**

I want to limit container's outgress bandwidth using docker default bridge "docker0" and ovs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfryP.png)

My Idea is create ovs bridge and locate between eth0 and docker0. But I don't have any knowledge to judge this idea can be implemented.

There are possibility that this idea can be implemented?

If yes, please let me know what should i study for this can be work.

If also tc can be work for limiting container outgress bandwidth, please teach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create any funky chain of bridges in Linux:

The trick is how to join to bridges together. There are two options:
1) Use so-called 'patch' link type in OVS (works only between two OVS bridges). (The first found article about this on the internet: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/11/27/connecting-ovs-bridges-with-patch-ports/)

2) Universal way to join any two bridges (even OVS with br-tools, or any other bridge-like things together): use veth.

Veth is a virtal ethernet interface: when you create it, it creates two interfaces at once (f.e. `veth0` and `veth1`). All traffic coming into `veth0` coming out of `veth1`, all traffic coming into `veth1` coming out of `veth0`. You can plug veth0 into your `docker0` bridge and `veth1` into bridge of your choice (let's say `mybrige`).

Commands to do this:

```
ip link add type veth  # check out ip link list command to see new interfaces
ip link set up dev veth0 # names may be different
ip link set up dev veth1
ovs-vsctl add-br mybridge
ovs-vsctl add-port mybridge veth0
ovs-vsctl add-port mybrige eth0
brctl addif docker0 veth1 # I'm not sure what kind of bridge docker uses, may be it's ovs-vsctl add-port docker0 veth1
```

Bonus fact: veth is a proper linux eth interface and it can be shaped/filtered as you wish.

Comment: Hi. I've done what you told me, but I do not know how to route packets through the bridge **mybridge**. Can i route packets through the bridge by using iptables?

Comment: Bridges cannot  route anything, they work on L2 (routing is L3). Bridges can pass ethernet frames between ports, that's all.